# Can I test my app on IPhone without enrolling in developer program?

Tags: ios, swift, testing

I'm relatively new to Swift, and I've been using the iOS simulator. It works, but I want to test my program on my iPhone. I've done a lot of searching for a way, and it looks like I'll have to pay $$99 *to test an app I created on my iPhone.* I don't want to release it on the app store. Did I overlook something, or will I have to pay $99?

EDIT: I may have been unclear about where I'd pay the 99$. It says I have to enroll in a developer program ($99).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It Seems that starting from Xcode 7 you won't need a paid account to test on your device anymore. 
http://gadgets.ndtv.com/mobiles/news/paid-membership-no-longer-required-to-develop-and-test-ios-apps-swift-2-will-be-open-source-701507

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you will have to pay to enroll in the Developer Program. This permits you to test your application on your phone and release it on the App Store. Please take a read through https://developer.apple.com/support/ for more information.

2016 Edit: This is no longer the case. You can test on your device before enrolling in the Developer Program. https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/LaunchingYourApponDevices/LaunchingYourApponDevices.html

Answer (score 1):

To test on real device without paying you have to jailbreak your iPhone. Or you can use the simulator.

see : [tutorial to debug on jailbroken iphone](http://www.grobinson.me/developing-and-debugging-my-own-apps-on-jailbroken-ios8-1-using-xcode-6-1-without-paying-apple/)

Answer (score 0):

You must enroll in iOS Developer Program if you want to test your code on the iPhone and release on the APP Store. You can use iPhone Simulator otherwise for learning for normal use. Here is the [link](https://developer.apple.com/programs/ios/) for developer program and for more details use this https://developer.apple.com/support/